# scikit fitting data error

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, scikit-learn, svm

I am trying to implement a learning algorithm for predicting whether an image has a target value of `1` or `0`. First, my target values are set as so...

```
real = [1] * len(images)
fake = [0] * len(fake_images)

total_target = real + fake
total_target = numpy.array(total_target)

>>> [1 1 1 ... 0 0 0 0]
```

Next I convert a list of images into a `numpy` array of `numpy` arrays. So I store each image as a `numpy` array...

```
training_set = []
for image in total_images:
    im = image.convert("L")
    dataset = numpy.asarray(im)
    training_set.append(dataset)
training_set = numpy.array(training_set)
```

So `training_set` holds the images. The order of the `training_set` corresponds to the order of the `total_target`, so the first image in `training_set` corresponds to the first value in `total_target` which would be `1` in the example above.

Next I flatten out the training set...

```
n_samples = len(training_set)
data = training_set.reshape((n_samples, -1))
```

Now I pass it into the following...

```
classifier = svm.SVC(gamma=0.001)
classifier.fit(data[:n_samples-1], total_target[:n_samples-1])
```

I did not include the last image and its respective value because this is the value I want to predict...

```
expected = total_target[-1]
predicted = classifier.predict(data[-1])
```

When I run all this, I get the following error...

> DeprecationWarning: Passing 1d arrays as data is deprecated in 0.17 and willraise ValueError in 0.19. Reshape your data either using X.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature or X.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample.
>     DeprecationWarning)

OK, so by the error it looks like my `total_target` is in the wrong format, so I add the following...

```
total_target = numpy.array(total_target).reshape(-1, 1)
```

I run it and now I get the following errors

> DataConversionWarning: A column-vector y was passed when a 1d array was expected. Please change the shape of y to (n_samples, ), for example using ravel(). y_ = column_or_1d(y, warn=True)
>
> C:\Users\Eric\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py:386: DeprecationWarning: Passing 1d arrays as data is deprecated in 0.17 and willraise ValueError in 0.19. Reshape your data either using X.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature or X.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample.
>     DeprecationWarning)

I tried using `ravel()` on `total_target` but it just takes me back to the error before. I think my formatting is wrong I am quite new to `numpy` arrays.

Comment: `OK, so by the error it looks like my total_target is in the wrong format,` - No, scikit-learn is complaining that `data[-1]` is a flat vector instead of a 2d array. `total_target` is supposed to be a flat vector and it is, no need to change that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Numpy's [`atleast_2d`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.atleast_2d.html) gets the code to work.

Let us first generate some mock data, namely 5 real and 5 fake 8-bit images of 800 rows by 1200 columns:

```
In [111]: import numpy as np

In [112]: real, fake = 5, 5

In [113]: rows, cols = 800, 1200

In [114]: bits = 8

In [115]: target = np.hstack([np.ones(real), np.zeros(fake)])

In [116]: np.random.seed(2017)

In [117]: images = np.random.randint(2**bits, size=(real + fake, rows, cols))

In [118]: data = images.reshape(images.shape[0], -1)

In [119]: data
Out[119]: 
array([[ 59,   9, 198, ..., 189, 201,  38],
       [150, 251, 145, ...,  95, 214, 175],
       [156, 212, 220, ..., 179,  63,  48],
       ..., 
       [ 25,  94, 108, ..., 159, 144, 216],
       [179, 103, 217, ...,  92, 219,  34],
       [198, 209, 177, ...,   6,   4, 144]])

In [120]: data.shape
Out[120]: (10L, 960000L)
```

Then we train the classifier using all but the last image:

```
In [121]: from sklearn import svm

In [122]: classifier = svm.SVC(gamma=0.001)

In [123]: classifier.fit(data[:-1], target[:-1])
Out[123]: 
SVC(C=1.0, cache_size=200, class_weight=None, coef0=0.0,
  decision_function_shape=None, degree=3, gamma=0.001, kernel='rbf',
  max_iter=-1, probability=False, random_state=None, shrinking=True,
  tol=0.001, verbose=False)
```

If you try now to classify the last image through `classifier.predict(data[-1])`, sklearn complains. To make sklearn happy you just need to ensure that the test data is two-dimensional like this:

```
In [124]: classifier.predict(np.atleast_2d(data[-1]))
Out[124]: array([ 1.])
```